# Use the Bluetooth LE Proximity Profile PXP with Bluez (5.17)

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, proximity, bluez, gatt

I want to run a BLE Profile called ["Proximity Profile" or PXP](https://developer.bluetooth.org/TechnologyOverview/Pages/PXP.aspx) on a Linux machine with bluez-5.17 installed.

PXP is, if i understand correctly, a collection of three ble services:

- Link Loss Service
- Immediate Alert Service
- Tx Power Service

What i did so far. I followed the installation instructions on [this site](http://urbanjack.wordpress.com/2014/04/02/howto-install-bluez-and-dbus/).
Installation seems to be sucessfull.

I could run *hciconfig hci0 up* and *hcitool lescan*.

So but now i want to run the PXP profile and let the BLE USB dongle act as the gatt-server.

In the folder `/etc/bluetooth/` is a file called **proximity.conf**. There is only one Option to set `called Disable="..."`. Since i want to enable all services i just removed every thing behind the equals-sign.

In the same folder is a file called `main.conf` where i changed the option to **AttributeServer = true**. (Not sure if this was really necessary because in the text below i written that this is only useful for testing)

In `/var/lib/bluetooth/xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx/` i added uuids of the services in the "profiles" file. For `00001803-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb` for LinkLoss.

So i restarted the bluetooth service and expected it to work.

On the other side i have a two android apps as Proximity Reporter (gatt client). The first app is from the TI.com sample code. It scan and shoes all the gatt attributes. i use it to check whether the services are running. i also found an app called nRF Toolbox for BLE.

To make the long story short it's not working and i even have no clue how to run this PXP service. I was just trying it. Thank for helping !

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the following options to figure out what is happening:

---

1. running dbus-monitor to get the logs
2. running bluetooth daemon(bluetoothd) in debug mode ie with -d option, so that logs could help figure out things